# how can I do a ping test on the terminal?

Tags: cmd.exe, ping

i dont test ping in my laptop. I've tried typing test ping in cmd but still can't 'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
interoperable programs or batch files.

[image: this is picture]

Answer (score 1):

**Ping test** to check your internet connection, you can ping `Google’s DNS` servers by entering in `cmd`

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

---

In order to see `continuous ping results` to see if your connection to `Google’s DNS` servers ever times out.

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -t
```

More about `ping` command, hit in `cmd`

```
ping /?
```